# .NETのWebBrowserでSSLクライアント認証が必要なページを表示できない

Tags: .net, ssl, internet-explorer

.NETのWebBrowserコントロールを使用したSSLクライアント認証が必要なページを表示するフォームをVB.NETで作成しています。.NET Frameworkは4.5です。

フォームのプログラムは

```
Me.webBrowserCtrl.Url = New Uri("https://xxxx/xxx/xxx.html")
```

と作成しました。

Windows7＋InternetExplorer11の環境で、

- IEにルートCA証明書とクライアント証明書をインストール
- インターネットオプション→セキュリティで、対象ページのドメインを「信頼済みサイト」に追加
- 続いて「信頼済みサイト」の「レベルのカスタマイズ」で「既存のクライアント証明書が１つしか存在しない場合の証明書の選択」を「有効にする」に設定

以上の設定をするとIEから対象ページにアクセスした時に「クライアント証明書の選択ダイアログ」が表示されないことを確認しました。
その上で作成したフォームを起動すると正しく対象ページを表示することができました。

ところがWindowsServer2012R2＋InternetExplorer11の環境では、
IEは上記環境のとおり動作するのですが、作成したフォームでは「Web ページへのナビゲーションは取り消されました」が表示されアクセスできません。
Windows7環境でも「既存のクライアント証明書が１つしか存在しない場合の証明書の選択」を「無効にする」とした場合に同様の状態になりましたので、この設定がWindowsServer2012R2環境ではIEからWebBrowserコントロールに引き継がれないのでは？と推測しています。

WindowsServer2012R2＋InternetExplorer11の環境で、フォームアプリケーションでSSLクライアント認証が必要なページを表示する方法はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

自己解決しました。

WebBrowserコントロールの「ScriptErrorsSuppressed」プロパティをTrueにしていたのが原因のようです。
このプロパティをFalseにすると、WindowsServer2012R2＋IE11でも無事動作しました（ちなみにプロパティに関係なくHTTPプロトコルの通常のWebページはアクセスできました）。

しかしながら、この「ScriptErrorsSuppressed」プロパティがTrueの場合に

- Windows7＋IE11環境では通常のWebページおよびSSLクライアント認証必須ページ両方とも正常にアクセスできる。
- WindowsServer2012R2＋IE11環境では通常のWebページは正常にアクセスできるが、SSLクライアント認証必須ページはアクセスできない。

という現象が発生する理由は分からないままです。
今回はFalseで問題ありませんでしたが、Trueにする必要が出てきた場合を考えると頭が痛いです。